# Apple QuickTake™ 150 camera pictures in QuickDraw format…

Tags: file-conversion, image-processing

**Apple QuickTake 150 camera** pictures in "**QuickDraw picture**" format cannot be opened by any software I have.

At some point in the dark reaches of the past, I recall being able to Save As… but at the time, I was ignorant of what was to come and was concerned with using as little disk space as possible. 150KB seemed big at the time.

I think the files are compressed as a few .tiff format duplicates fluff-up to over 6X its native format size. Preview shows the thumbnail image as it is compatible; but, the image is blank.

Now, years later, I would like to recover as much of as many past family photos as I can.
It may be that some utility is available. I'm patient and I have a few minutes — my alternative is futility.

Greedy me. I want it all. TIA

Comment: See [this page](https://www.lifewire.com/pct-file-2622172) about how to open these files. YMMV. (I don't have any QuickDraw picture format files to test this, although I have a QuickTake 100 camera in my Apple museum.

Comment: @IconDaemon LOL I've been told a few times I could start a small Apple museum with all of the Apple paraphernalia (hardware and software) etc I still have laying around!

Comment: Stan, I can think of a number of possible options here. I could try adding a rather lengthy answer explaining them all, but if you're open to it (and I totally get you may not be), would you be willing to share a couple for me to test on first?

Comment: dcraw has support for QuickTake 100 and 150 cameras. It can be installed via brew on the command line on macOS. If dcraw can handle your images, you could then convert them to something easier to handle, e.g. jpg.

Comment: I seem to recall GraphicConverter able to open pretty much any graphic file format, including those embedded in a resource fork. Haven't used it in a while but I believe there is a "test" version available to see if it does what you want.

Comment: Did you try graphic converter? https://www.lemkesoft.de/en/products/graphicconverter/key-features/import-and-export-formats/

Answer (score 3):

I was in the same situation. Finding photos I had taken 20 years ago on my Quicktake 150, but was not able to open them. But I found a solution. There is a OS 9 emulator for OSX that i installed, then i installed the quicktake on the os 9 system abd was able to open and then resave the pics as tiff that OSX can open.

Comment: Can you add some details about where to get the emulator from and how to get the photos from the QuickTake to the emulator?

Answer (score 3):

## dcraw

[`dcraw`](http://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/) is an open source application will open and convert images from the 
QuickTake cameras:

> So here is my mission: Write and maintain an ANSI C program that decodes any raw image from any digital camera on any computer running any operating system.
>
> That program is called dcraw (pronounced "dee-see-raw"), and it's become a standard tool within and without the Open Source world. It's small (about 9000 lines), portable (standard C libraries only), free (both "gratis" and "libre"), and when used skillfully, produces better quality output than the tools provided by the camera vendor.
>
> ### Supported Cameras
>
> ...
>
> - Apple QuickTake 100
> - Apple QuickTake 150
> - Apple QuickTake 200

## GIMP and UFRaw

If you prefer a graphical application, [GIMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIMP), which is a feature rich free photo editing program, along with [UFRaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UFRaw), again free will open QuickTake `.wtk` files on both Apple and PC computers.

> UFRaw reads raw images, using [`dcraw`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dcraw) as a back end, and supports color management via LittleCMS, allowing the user to apply input, output, and display color profiles (see also Linux color management). This allows UFRaw to support a large number of raw image formats. (`.orf`; any format supported by DCRaw)
>   Hope this helps and prevents the need to load an OS simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Apple QuickTake image files are in a proprietary Apple compression format.  The only way you will be able to open them is with an old computer running no newer operating system than OS 9 and have the Apple QuickTake CDEV loaded into the control panels, and there may (but I don't think so) an INIT file required too.

If you don't have the older (PPC)computer, Older OS (8.1 to 9.2), you'll never get them open.  I have an older computer and I know I had the CDEV, but I've yet to get the old computer up and running. Years ago I restored most of my old QuickTake photos, but have since run across some more, so I'm at it again, trying to get the old nag running again to restore those forgotten images.

Comment: Thank you for this. I vaguely remember a software development company in Seattle that developed the application for Apple. Thank you for the idea. Happily, I have a PowerBook 640 (Motorola CPU) that maybe I can resuscitate something. I feel like a time traveller.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to open the images on a system they would have originally been used with, a Classic Mac running System 7.5 to Mac OS 9, you need to have the QuickTake Image extension in your Extensions folder.

The extension is part of the [QuickTake Software](https://macintoshgarden.org/apps/quicktake-software), and is also provided as a loose file on the QuickTake Image 2.0.1 disk that you can drag into the System Folder if you don't want to install the rest of the software.